# Core Data Multiple Item Edit Efficiency and Random Error

Tags: ios, core-data

I hope this isn't a duplicate question. I can't seem to find anything similar. Most core data questions seem to be about new object creation...

I have a program with a database of around 23,000 items. I'm attempting to create an export/import function to send data to other devices (not linked with iCloud).

The export works just fine, as does the email...

I have the import functioning, but it functions slowly (and, more on this later, doesn't seem to work well with the iPhone 5 or iPad 3)

I have a function that parses the data I'm importing into an NSArray (_importedRows), then I run the following code:

```
self.managedObjectContext = [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];

    NSManagedObjectContext *ctx = self.managedObjectContext;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"CHECKLIST"
                                   inManagedObjectContext:ctx];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    ImportedData *importedData;
    NSString *verify;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObject *updatedObject;
    NSArray *matchingItems;
    for (int i = 0; i < [_importedRows count]; i++) {
        importedData = [_importedRows objectAtIndex:i];
        verify = importedData.uniqueID;
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uniqueID == %@", verify]];
        [fetchRequest setFetchLimit:1];
        matchingItems = [ctx executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

        for (updatedObject in matchingItems) {
            HUD.detailsLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Updating %@" , [updatedObject valueForKey:@"figureName"]];
            [updatedObject setValue:importedData.numberOwned forKey:@"numberOwned"];
            [updatedObject setValue:importedData.numberWanted forKey:@"wishList"];
            [updatedObject setValue:importedData.availableTrade forKey:@"tradeList"];

        }

        [ctx save:&error];

        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"error saving managed object context: %@", error);
        }

    }
```

Basically, I'm grabbing a core data entity, and then looping through my array checking for matches. When I find a match (the uniqueID predicate), I'm updating the object with the imported data. This code works fine on my iPhone 4s, but rather slowly. 4,000 items takes around 4-5 minutes. Am I doing anything blatantly wrong? Should I be calling the save function more frequently?

As a bonus, for some reason this code almost never works when I test it on an iPhone 5. 9 times out of 10 (and 50% of the time on my iPad 3) I get a

"Jan 14 08:06:44 : *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil'"

in the console. Thoughts?

Let me know if more details are needed!

UPDATE:
It seems that handleOpenURL is being called twice... once in applicationdidfinishlaunching
`NSURL *url = (NSURL *)[launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];
    if (url != nil && [url isFileURL]) {
        [self.window.rootViewController performSelector:@selector(showWithLabel:) withObject:url afterDelay:6];
    }`

and once here:

```
-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

> { if (url != nil && [url isFileURL]) {
>             [self.window.rootViewController performSelector:@selector(showWithLabel:)   withObject:url];
>         }
>         return YES;
>     }

I have to lave both those in the app delegate, otherwise the function won't always get called (once is for when the application launches, and once if it the application was already in the background, I believe) - I've added a check to prevent it from launching a second time within the showWithLabel thread, but it doesn't seem like that is a very elegant solution...

UPDATE: @mundi advised cleaning up the fetchedresults code as follows:

```
NSArray *importedIDs = [_importedRows valueForKeyPath:@"uniqueID"];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    fetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CHECKLIST"
                                      inManagedObjectContext:ctx];
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                              @"uniqueID in %@", importedIDs];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObject *updatedObject;
    NSArray *matchingItems;
    matchingItems = [ctx executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    ImportedData *importedData;
    for (int i = 0; i < [_importedRows count]; i++) {
        importedData = [_importedRows objectAtIndex:i];
        for (updatedObject in matchingItems) {
            if ([importedData.uniqueID isEqualToString:[updatedObject valueForKey:@"uniqueID"]]) {
                HUD.detailsLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Updating %@" , [updatedObject valueForKey:@"figureName"]];
                [updatedObject setValue:importedData.numberOwned forKey:@"numberOwned"];
                [updatedObject setValue:importedData.numberWanted forKey:@"wishList"];
                [updatedObject setValue:importedData.availableTrade forKey:@"tradeList"];
            }


        }
    }


    [ctx save:&error];
```

I'm sure it could still be a little cleaner and the actual updating portion (I'm not sure how to do it other than compare each item in the fetchedresults with each item in the initial array to make sure they are updated correctly, but the combined fetchedresults increased the speed tremendously (originally 240 seconds for 4000 items, now between 80-120 seconds)

sorting arrays first, then updating in order speeds it up tremendously yet again:

```
NSArray *matchingItemsSorted;
    matchingItemsSorted = [matchingItems sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
        NSString *first = [a valueForKey:@"uniqueID"];
        NSString *second = [b valueForKey:@"uniqueID"];
        return [first caseInsensitiveCompare:second];
    }];


    NSArray *importedRowsSorted;
    importedRowsSorted = [_importedRows sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
        NSString *first = [a valueForKeyPath:@"uniqueID"];
        NSString *second = [b valueForKeyPath:@"uniqueID"];
        return [first caseInsensitiveCompare:second];
    }];

    int i = 0;
    for (updatedObject in matchingItemsSorted) {
        NSLog(@"do we match? %@  :  %@", [[importedRowsSorted objectAtIndex:i] valueForKeyPath:@"uniqueID"], [updatedObject valueForKey:@"uniqueID"]);
        HUD.detailsLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Updating %@" , [updatedObject valueForKey:@"figureName"]];
        [updatedObject setValue:[[importedRowsSorted objectAtIndex:i] valueForKeyPath:@"numberOwned"] forKey:@"numberOwned"];
        [updatedObject setValue:[[importedRowsSorted objectAtIndex:i] valueForKeyPath:@"numberWanted"] forKey:@"wishList"];
        [updatedObject setValue:[[importedRowsSorted objectAtIndex:i] valueForKeyPath:@"availableTrade"] forKey:@"tradeList"];
        i++;


    }
```

13 seconds or so for 4000 items with the nslog there... the only weird thing now is that when I comment out the nslog, it frequently crashes... is it happening so fast it's breaking core data - when it doesn't crash, it only takes about 4 seconds?

Thanks,
Zack

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an option for you but what I do is update my objects on a background thread so even while it takes a minute or 2, it user can still use the app. I am not sure if there is anything you can do to make your updating faster-- I looked into it at one point and what your doing was the fastest method for me.

Comment: Please have a look at [Implementing Find-or-Create Efficiently](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174-SW4) in the "Core Data Programming Guide" which describes a nice pattern that uses one single fetch request, instead of one fetch request per item. Also save *less often*, not *more often*.

Comment: Martin R - yes, I see now I'm saving after ever loop, so I'll change that to every 100th or 1000th... I was concerned about a fetch request of 4,000+ items... perhaps I shouldn't be?

Comment: @ZacharyFisher: I do not have practical experience with *large* data sets in Core Data, but I know that a fetch request (by default) returns a list of fault (placeholder) objects, and fetches the properties only on demand. Another option is to import in batches with a dedicated autoreleasepool (also described in the "Core Data Programming Guide").

Comment: @MartinR interesting enough, if I add a modulus to save every 1000 [ie if (i % 1000 == 0) ] it slows it down considerably. every 1000 items is 88 seconds, while if I save every time, every 1000 items is 59 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two nested loops. Use this pattern to speed this up:

```
NSArray *importedIDs = [_importedRows valueForKeyPath:@"uniqueID"];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
fetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CHECKLIST"
                                  inManagedObjectContext:ctx];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
            @"uniqueID in %@", importedIDs];
```

Like this you can fetch one array with all matching items.

Comment: Interesting. I'm still using a nested loop because I need to compare each item in the array against each fetched item to update the correct values, right? it did cut 50% of the time though! awesome  'for (int i = 0; i < [_importedRows count]; i++) {
            importedData = [_importedRows objectAtIndex:i];
            for (updatedObject in matchingItems) {
                if ([importedData.uniqueID isEqualToString:[updatedObject valueForKey:@"uniqueID"]]) {'

Comment: Wow, it pulled it down from 240 seconds to about 70 on my wife's iPhone 5... I'm going with that as the answer... although it's possible by second nesting is not actually necessary either? Thoughts? I'll put the full code in the original question to make it easier to read

Comment: You definitely have to eliminate the double loop. 70 seconds is ridiculous. Sort the arrays by uniqueID and then do data copying in one go.

Comment: I've updated the code above to pre-sort the arrays... drops it to under 15 seconds WITH an nslog verifying they match... weird thing is when I comment out the nslog, it frequently crashes, almost as if it is happening too fast... (it only takes 4 seconds or so when it doesn't crash) I do get a low memory warning (perhaps from all the nsarrays) before I even start updating the data set...

Comment: Well, from 240 to 4. That's what I call a performance improvement! You can maybe reduce the memory footprint by using `@autoreleasepool` and perhaps there is even a batching strategy. Another try would be to use `NSDictionaryResultType` and only fetch the attributes you need.

Comment: Yes, it's great... Thanks! I'd like to figure out the random crash though on the increased speed. Perhaps I should be using a second managedObjectContext to make the changes then merge them back with the first?